# Higher derivative test for maxima and minima

Tags: derivatives

Let $f'(x_{0})=f''(x_{0})=....=f^{(n-1)}(x_{0})=0$ but $f^{(n)}(x_{0})\neq0$.

Case 1:
If n is even, then at $f^{(n)}(x_{0})<0$ there is maximum at $x_{0}$ and at $f^{(n)}(x_{0})>0$ there is a minimum at $x_{0}$.

Case 2:
If n is odd then there is no extremum at $x_{0}$.

I have understood Case 1 as it says in my textbook. Can someone please explain me Case 2.

Comment: Didn't your textbook explain anything about proving the second case? As it seems it did, try to explain in what section did you have a problem in understanding it.

Comment: Think about $f(x) = x^3$ at $x=0.$

Answer (score 2):

According to Taylor's formula

$ f(x) = f(x_0) + \cdots + \dfrac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!} (x-x_0)^n + o((x-x_0)^n),x \to x_0$

so,if $n$ is odd, as you stated, the above equation becomes

$ f(x) =\dfrac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!} (x-x_0)^n + o((x-x_0)^n),x \to x_0$

Assume $f^{(n)}(x_0)>0$. So, if $x > x_0$ in a small neighbourhood of $x_0$, $f(x) > f(x_0)$(since $(x-x_0)^n > 0$), and in the left $x<x_0$, $f(x)< f(x_0)$(since $(x-x_0)^n < 0$, recall that $n$ is odd) ,which means there is no extremum at $x_0$

Comment: I think your second equation should be: $f^{n}(x)=...$, i.e., the LHS should be the n-th derivative of $f(x)$

Comment: Since they are all $0$,the assumption of the problem tells us.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Since, $f(x_0)=f'(x_0)=\cdots = f^{(n-1)}(x_0)=0$

Comment: Understood, thanks!